# MSDEPLOY: How can I access the command generated by Visual Studio

Tags: msdeploy

How can I access the MSDEPLOY command line generated by Visual Studio 2010.

I am asking because when I manually run MSDEPLOY I can easly deploy on a remote server and when I run it throught Visual Studio, I get this error

Web deployment task failed.(Remote Agent (url https://x.x.x.x:8172/msdeply.axd?site=Default Web Site) could not be contacted
Make sure the remote agent service is installed and started on the target computer.
An unsupported response was received. The response header 'MSDeploy.Response' was '' but 'v1' was expected

The remote server returned an error:(404) not found

Comment: I seem to have the same issue, what is the error that you're getting?

Comment: I am using two different servers and oneach of them, i am having this error: Web Deployment task failed , remote agent could not be contacted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you follow this guys instructions you can see more verbose output:

http://sedodream.com/2010/11/04/WebDeployHowToSeeTheCommandExecutedInVisualStudioDuringPublish.aspx

FYI, I tested this myself because MSDeploy.exe from the command line was working but the Publish form Visual Studio 2010 wasn't working (using Web Deploy).  MSBuild gave me the error messages I needed to fix my issues.

My issues were specifically that the web server I was deploying to did not have .NET 4 installed, and therefore the App Pools were set to 2.0.  Visual Studio in all it's greatness says nothing about this, but MSBuild did.  After that, I had an ACL issue and had to add another delegation rule in addition to the ones they tell you to add in the intro guides.

Comment: This was a good solution.  Can you edit this answer to add the instructions from that page?  Ideally SO answers should be self-contained.  Just the "create a file called {Project}.wpp.targets, and add <this> to it" part...

Comment: You saved my monitor from going out the window with this.

Comment: Awesome! Glad this helped.  Sorry I haven't had the chance to flesh out the actual solution, no time!